# Mapeamento de exceções .NET para códigos de status HTTP

Tags: .net, exceção, http-status, recuperação-de-erros

### Situação

Eu estou implementanto um *HttpModule* que é responsável por monitorar padrões de uso e interceptar e gerenciar exceções não tratadas em aplicações ASP.NET via eventos `BeginRequest`, `EndRequest` and `Error` do contexto atual da `HttpApplication`.

### Questão

Existe alguma maneira direta e já implementada para mapear *exceptions* da plataforma .NET para seus equivalentes HTTP? Eu posso imaginar que alguns mapeamentos seriam:

```
FileNotFoundException       > 404 File Not Found
UnauthorizedAccessException > 403 Forbidden
AuthenticationException     > 401 Unauthorized
[...]
(Qualquer outra exceção)  > 500 Internal Server Error
```

Eu não quero reinventar a roda, e prefiro utilizar alguma função já implementada (de preferência nativa da plataforma).

Comment: Seu sistema é ASP.NET MVC?

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez Na verdade não, Morrison - a implementação atual é completamente agnóstica, SaaS.

Comment: Bom, se seguisse o padrão do MVC eu tinha uma resposta prontinha.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Solução

*Exceptions* podem sofrer *cast* para o tipo `HttpException`, e a partir deste tipo o método `GetHttpCode()` pode ser chamado:

```
        try
        {
            throw new FileNotFoundException("Teste");
        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            var httpException = err as HttpException;
            if (httpException != null)
            {
                var httperror = httpException.GetHttpCode();
                // O valor de httperror é 404.
            }
        }
```

Fonte: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/619895/how-can-i-properly-handle-404-in-asp-net-mvc

Comment: Considerando que você usou um link falando de ASP.NET MVC, a resposta que eu ia sugerir era de aproveitar um evento virtual da implementação do `Controller` chamado `OnException`. Por lá você pode obter o contexto da exceção e levantar uma mensagem mais genérica.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez Sim, eu diria que da maneira que você mencionou funcionaria perfeitamente.